# Generating an editable table that can be used as input

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, replacement, list-manipulation

Say I have a number $n_{max}$. I want a command to generate a table like

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
...
nmax nmax
```

where the second column is editable, and this table can be evaluated so that Mathematica treats the table as the set

```
replacement = { 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, ...}
```

(The point of this is so that I can replace the original list using /.replacement).

So for example, after generating the table above, I can edit the second column as follows

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
...
nmax FF
```

and this output re-evaluates into set

```
replacement = { 1-> A, 2-> B, 3-> C, F-> D, ... , nmax-> FF}
```

Comment: What do you mean by editable? Just use `Part`. `tmp = Transpose[{Range[4], Range[4]}]`. `tmp[[All, 2]] = {A, B, C, D}`. But don't use capitalised symbols.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Probably something like `a = RandomInteger[10,{5,2}]; TableView[Dynamic[a]]`.  **WARNING:**  `TableView` in undocumented, it might not work, and it has already crashed my Mathematica ... save your work before trying!

Comment: @Szabolcs It is unclear (to me) whether he wants to edit like a spreadsheet or "edit" programmatically, but I thought the latter. `TableView` changed in V9. It is now a `TableViewBox`. Before that it was built from other boxes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was unclear, but I wanted the former: just a table where the user can change any entry in the second column and have the table reevaluated as input.

Comment: I think it would be better if you explained why you want this... This is really a cumbersome way of doing it (although it might make perfect sense to you) and you will probably end up having to write more patchwork code for when things go wrong. If you explained your intention, then perhaps we can point you to the right way of doing it.

Comment: Care to comment on whether or not the answers address your question?

Answer (score 1):

How about this.  Generate a table of length `nmax`

```
nmax = 10; x = Table[{i, RandomInteger[]}, {i, 1, nmax}];
```

and use `InputField` to update the second column of the table

```
Column[{
  TableForm@
   Table[With[{i = i}, {x[[i, 1]], 
      InputField[Dynamic[x[[i, 2]]], FieldSize -> Tiny]}], {i, 1, 
     nmax}],
  replacement = Dynamic@x;
  }]
```

( The column is there just in case you want to remove the `;` and view the current value of `replacement`.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The symbol `replacement` is updated whenever the data in the second column is changed, and you can access a set of replacement rules using:

```
{#[[1]] -> #[[2]]} & /@ replacement[[1]]
(* {{1 -> 2}, {2 -> 3}, {3 -> 4}, {4 -> 5}, {5 -> 6}, {6 -> 0}, {7 -> 1}, {8 -> 0}, {9 -> 0}, {10 -> 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nMax = 10;
Block[{tab, boxes},
 tab = Table[
   {i, InputField[i]}
   ,
   {i, nMax}
   ];

 boxes = ToBoxes@TableForm[tab];

 boxes[[2]] = 
  Function[e, Print["replacement is updated"]; 
   replacement = #[[1]] -> #[[2, 1]] & /@ e];

 Cell[BoxData@boxes
   ,
   "Input"
   ] // CellPrint
 ]
```

Prints an input cell that looks like

[image]

which evaluates to

```
{1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 5}
```

and sets the variable `replacement` to be the result of evaluation above.

This is very similar to bobthechemists answer, but it relies less on `Dynamic`, which I think is nice. A downside of the code is that it assumes that the box generated by `ToBoxes@TableForm@tab` is a `TagBox` with a certain structure. That is why I used box expression in my previous answer, but the new code looks much cleaner.

I like the use of `InputFields` suggested by bobthechemist. Note that this allows one to "tab" through the table.