# Table with some editable cells

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, inputfield, editing

I have a table:

[image: Table I want to be editable]

I want it to be editable only where the zeros appear. I read this post [Generating an editable table that can be used as input](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41834/generating-an-editable-table-that-can-be-used-as-input) because it's almost exactly what I want, but I couln't figure out how to keep uneditable the first column AND the first row. I don't show the modifications I did because they wouldn't shed any light.

Answer (score 5):

I'll show you hoe to do it for a 3 x 3 matrix of values. You should be able to extend to 3 x 12 without much trouble

First do some initialization.

```
headers = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar"};
rowLbls = {" ", "Tmax", "Tmed", "Tmin"};
valTbl = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];
```

Next build the spreadsheet.

```
MapThread[Prepend, 
  {
    Prepend[
      Array[InputField[Dynamic@valTbl[[#1, #2]], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny] &, {3, 3}],
      headers],
   rowLbls
  }] // TableForm
```

[image: spreadsheet]

Finally a place to view the changes to `valTbl` as they occur.

```
Dynamic @ valTbl
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 42, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!